# how to select a row based on a single distinct value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, distinct

If i have 4 rows and want to select rows based on a single column's distinct values and dont mind which info it uses for the rest of the row, how do i do this? There doesn't seem to be a 'distinct' function for single cols whilst maintaining rest of row data.

eg

```
Name, value
john 1
john 2
michael 3
michael 5
```

result

```
john 1
michael 5
```

note it could have been john 2 or michael 3, i dont care which row for John or Michael it uses for the rest of the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY Name` and use any aggregate function with the `value` `MIN` or `MAX` since you don't care about the value of it:

```
SELECT Name, MIN(value)
FROM table
GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select a.* from TAbleName a
    inner join 
    (
     select distinct name,min(Id) as id  from TAbleName  
      group by name
    ) as b
    on a.name= b.name
    and a.id=b.id
```